# Workflow says "completed" with no Report Data [Solved]

Tags: workflow

Three list : Pending List , Trash List , Approved List

workflow : discussion Ideas

Step 1:

```
if Approval status Equals 2;#Pending

Set Officer to Pending
    then Wait for Approval status to not Equal 2;#Pending
```

Step 2:

```
if Approval status Equals 0;#Approved

Set Officer to Approved
    then Copy item in "Pending List" to "Approved List"
        then Delete item in "Pending List"

if Approval status Equals 1;#Rejected

Set Officer to Rejected
    then Copy item in "Pending List" to "Trash List"
        then Delete item in "Pending List"
```

---

i have created Workflow with name "discussion Ideas" and checked "Automatically start this wf when a new item is created".when i create Item and then Pressing F5 for refresh page , Workflow says "completed" with no Pending or Approved.
what's going on ? i am sure everything is fine also i don't see any report of WF.does MOSS is corrupt ? or maybe bad Installing ?
it took me an entire day to figure out that problem but couldn't.

here i took log from "SharePoint LogViewer 2.0"

[log file](http://www.4shared.com/zip/gl1XZK8D/Error_2007.html)

Any Help Would be Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to all

I am Really Sorry ,i Forgot to Click button "**Publish**"  in SPD 2010 so that i use this WF , LOL !!!

My Problem has Solved.once again i am sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Try having two conditions:

If Current Item:Approval Status equals 2;#Pending

and Current Item:Officer is empty (or whatever you want here)

Set Officer to Pending
then Log Officer Set to Pending to workflow history list
then Wait for Approval Status to not equal 2;#Pending

Make sure your workflow Start Options is set to Start workflow automatically when an item is created and changed. Since you are using Wait the next set of events will not happen unless an Edit is made to the Item which is why you will need to set the Workflow trigger on Change.

Set additional Logs to the Workflow History List in your Logic after each Action to assist with troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a workflow status is "Completed", that just means it didn't find any errors and got through the "maze" of the workflow with no errors, but it may not work like you are intending it to.

Whenever I do any workflow customizations, I always use "Log to history List" between each and every action. In addition this will output the variables, if any, that I need to track in the workflow. You will be able to then visually see how your workflow is being executed and you can determine where in the workflow the

Example:

```
if Approval status Equals 0;#Approved

Log to History "Setting Officer to Approved"**
then Set Officer to Approved
  then Log to History "Copying item in Pending List to Approved List"**
    then Copy item in "Pending List" to "Approved List"
      then Log to History "Deleting item in Pending List"**
        then Delete item in "Pending List"

if Approval status Equals 1;#Rejected

Log to History "Setting Officer to Rejected"**
 Set Officer to Rejected
   then Log to History "Copying item from Pending List to Trash List"**
     then Copy item in "Pending List" to "Trash List"
       then Log to History "Deleting item in Pending List"**
         then Delete item in "Pending List"
```